# Attaching a .avi file to an email

Tags: c#, email, avi

I'm trying to attach a video clip (.avi) to an email. Is there any way to do this within the .NET Framework 4.0?

My logic is that I need to open up that avi in some sort of file stream then attach that stream to the email and send it off. The part that I am struggling with is the getting the stream from the file.

Comment: Please provide code you tried so far - as of now your question does not match title - "struggling with getting the stream" is not exactly problem with sending e-mail.

Comment: I also solved this a different way.

`code` 
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\110906130800.avi", FileMode.Open);
Attachment EmailAttachment = new Attachment(stream, "Clip.avi");
`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, standard way to add attachments in .NET

```
MailMessage nMsg = new MailMessage();

nMsg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
nMsg.Subject = subject;

Attachment attachFile = new Attachment("Your file path here");
nMsg.Attachments.Add(attachFile);

SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient("yousmtpserver");
mailer.Send(nMsg);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. See the original post for another solution.